# how to find shared drive IP address if i have a path for that shared drive in java or cmd prompt

Tags: java, path, cmd, windows-share

I have a path windows network shared drive like this .

```
String url="//sample/data/Documents/network/test/";
```

How can i find the Ip address of the that drive using this path using a java program or cmd prompt?

Comment: You can't even know whether the path is using IP or some other protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although @Greg is right I think in most cases you can extract the host name from the URL and then use `InetAddress.getByName()`, i.e. something like the following

```
String host = url.substring(2).replaceFirst("/.*", "");
InetAddress.getByName(host);
```

Answer (score 2):

Via cmd prompt, you can get the IP pinging to 'sample' (following your example in the question) as the console must resolve hostname to IP address.

Via java, perhaps `InetAddress.getByName('sample')` could work.

All this assuming the shares are not going over NetBIOS and all the old stuff. That doesn't work over IP as the comment says.

Answer (score 0):

Open windows cmd prompt, type in nslookup \network_share_drive_name it will come back with name and address of your gateway server and the network share drive. Here you can type nslookup \sample